esp32 using screw terminal with analog and digital inputs
I am designing a board that will have two screw terminals connected to GPIO32 and GPIO33. I am including a schematic of the design:

Because GPIO 32 qnd 33 can be used for digital and analog inputs, i added the 2N7002 so i can connect sensors that are 5v or 3v.
However, i just realised that eventhough you can input uop to 3.3v to a pin in the esp32, the maximum voltage that can be used in an analog pin is 2.45 that is using the maximum attenuation.
My question is, how can i modify the design so that the voltage going to the pin is never more than 2.45v? the 3.3v that is being fed to the low side of the transistor comes from the voltage regulator, should i put a divider and bring it down to 2.45 and feed that to the low side? and if i do what happens when i am using a sensor with digital output?
Would love to get some suggestions

You should be fine, giving 3.3V on the analog pin. From my experience it doesn't hurt the ESP. You might not get any useful readings after 2.8V tho
